# Wagtail model with ParentalKey cannot translate along with the other models

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am working on a Wagtail CMS project. Everything has been working fine so far. But when I started translating each model field using Wagtail-modeltranslation package (wagtail-modeltranslation==0.6.0rc1), the model with ParentalKey is not showing properly in my admin interface. I am including my model and translation.py files along with this. It would be greate if someone gives a helping hand to find a solution to this problem.

```
class HomePage(Page):

# Home page fields

    home_page_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    short_description = RichTextField(null=True, blank=True)
    main_image = models.ForeignKey('wagtailimages.Image', null=True, 
                              blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                              related_name='+')

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [ 

          FieldPanel('home_page_title'),
          ...
          ...
          ...
         InlinePanel('related_partners', label="Related Parnters"),


#Child class


class Partner(Orderable):

    partners = ParentalKey(TranslationChild, 
                           related_name='related_partners', null=True, 
                           blank=True)
    partner_image = models.ForeignKey('wagtailimages.Image', 
                                     null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                related_name='+')
    partner_url = models.URLField(max_length=500)
```

And my translation.py file looks like this,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from .models import HomePage, TranslationChild, Partner
from wagtail_modeltranslation.translation import TranslationOptions
from modeltranslation.decorators import register


@register(HomePage)
class FooTR(TranslationOptions):
    fields = (
        'home_page_title',
        'short_description',
        'body',
        'translation_section_title',
        )



@register(Partner)
class PartnerTR(TranslationOptions):
    fields = (
        'partner_description',
        'partners',
    )
```

Here in the admin page, the partner section is not showing properly. Django version 1.8.5 and Wagtail version 1.9

Comment: Is there a solution to this problem?